# Array not returning strings

Tags: java, arrays

**This is assessed work so please don't give the answer, just advice!**

I'm trying to get my program to return the strings pass, compensation pass or fail depending on the values inputted by the user. However, it's not returning the values and I'm receiving an error for 'weighting'. Earlier it was working, however not in a suitable way because it wouldn't always return the correct before results. I added the array because i think that's what is needed, but now I'm just getting an error. Cheers.

```
enter code here

public class MarkCalculator {
static int[] marks = new int[12];
static int[] weighing = new int[6];

// public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int weighting;
    int coursework;
    int exammark;

    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length / 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter course work weighting");
        weighting = kb.nextInt();
        weighing[i] = weighting;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length / 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter course work mark ");
        coursework = kb.nextInt();
        marks[i] = coursework;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length / 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter exam mark ");
        exammark = kb.nextInt();
        marks[i + 6] = exammark;
    }

    System.out.println("Calculating Marks");
    MarkCalculator mc = new MarkCalculator();
    String[] results = mc.computeMarks(marks, weighing);

    for (String result : results) {

        System.out.println("Results are " + result);
    }

}

public String[] computeMarks(int[] marks, int[] weighing) {
    int[] formula = new int[12];
    String[] results = new String[weighing.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < weighing.length; i++) {
        int exam = marks[i];
        int cw = marks[i+weighing.length];
        int weight = weighing[i];

        formula [i]= ((cw + weight) + (exam * (100 - weight)) / 100);

        if ((formula[i]<=39) && (formula[i] > 35)) {
            results[i] = "COMPENSATION PASS";}

        else if (formula[i] >= 40) {
            results[i] = "PASS";
        } 
        else {
            results[i] = "FAIL";
        }
    }
    return results;
}

public static void computeResult (int[] coursework, int[] exammark)
{

    computeResult(coursework,exammark);




}
```

}

Comment: "i'm receiving an error" What is the the error? On which line is it?

Comment: It might be advisable to change the range of the first `for` loop so that is is from `0` to `weightings.length` as this seems to be what you are setting. This is easier to read and less likely to let bugs creep in if you change the length of the `weightings` array. You might however have a reason for choosing to use `marks.length / 2`.

Comment: line 51 "int weight = weighing[i];" and line 36 "String[] results = mc.computeMarks(marks, weighing);"

Answer (score 0):

`weighting` and `marks` are different length arrays, yet you are doing the loop

`for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)`

which will go out of bounds for `weighting` when `i > 5`.

It looks like you need to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weighting.length; i++) {
        int cw = marks[i];
        int exam = marks[i+weighting.length];
        int weight = weighing[i];
```

But that will depend on how you are storing the marks for the cw and exam in the `marks` array. I would recommend creating separate arrays for cw and exam as these are different items and will make things a lot easier to read and debug for yourself.

Comment: yeah, that does work. However it doesn't seem to be following my IF statement correctly because, the grade results aren't coming out correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that is likely because I have guessed at how you have stored the data. My example was to highlight that your `marks` array is twice the size of the `weightings` array. In my example I have assumed that the first 6 elements of `marks` are exam marks and the last 6 are cw marks, but I can see from code that it's actually the other way around. I'm going to edit my answer to give you some more tips.

Comment: The weighting is only the waiting of the coursework that's the reason i've used 6. Cheers.

Comment: In which case it might be worth having two variables `NUM_EXAMS` and `NUM_CW` (see my other answer above), unless you are always going to have the same number of exams as cw.

Comment: @user2961364 - Also, you should accept an answer if it has solved your original problem.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. But still, it wasn't really the imporvement/efficiency of my code that i wanted help with. The main problem is that the strings returned pass ect aren't correct based on the numbers i've got in my code

Comment: I think the point is that you've made it hard for yourself to see where things are going wrong because you have not defined some appropriate variables that would make the code easier to manage. I can't tell why you are getting wrong answers unless you post up what your input, expected and actual outputs are. It would also help to have more background to the problem you are trying to solve, as we are currently just guessing from the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Was posted as comment:

You could separate the marks into two arrays which will be easier to debug? Also it seems like you might be going over the array index for weightings on this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length;i++) 
{ 
    int exam = marks[i]; 
    int cw = marks[i]; 
    int weight = weighing[i]; // Error is here
    //...
}
```

Because "weighing" has a range 0-5 and you are cycling through to 0-11 (with the marks array)

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter an error as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6"

This is because in method computeMarks. The length of marks (int[]) is 12.

and you just declare a variable with length 6 to handle:

```
int[] formula = new int[6];
```

when variable i in for loop reaches 6. The following code will throw out an error.

```
formula [i]= ((cw + weight) + (exam * (100 - weight)) / 100);
```

Have a try to declare it with length of 12.

```
int[] formula = new int[12];
```

Just paste code for method **computeMarks**.

public String[] computeMarks(int[] marks, int[] weighing) {
        int[] formula = new int[12];
        String[] results = new String[weighing.length];

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < weighing.length; i++) {
        sb.setLength(0);

        int exam = marks[i];
        int cw = marks[i + weighing.length];
        int weight = weighing[i];
        formula[i] = ((cw + weight) + (exam * (100 - weight)) / 100);

        if ((formula[i] <= 39) && (formula[i] > 35)) {
            sb.append("COMPENSATION PASS");
        } else if (formula[i] >= 40) {
            sb.append("PASS");
        } else {
            sb.append("FAIL");
        }
        sb.append(" cw mark is ").append(cw).append(" and exam mark is ")
                .append(exam);
        results[i] = sb.toString();
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: The coursework and exam marks get combined that's the reason i put it down as 6. I tried this, still receiving an error

Comment: To avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You need to make sure the index is not out of range. The length of result (String[]) is 6. Then length of marks is 12. This could be greater than 5, which will exceed the range of result (String[]). Code  int weight = weighing[i]; will also alse cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I'm not receiving an error anymoe but i'm not being given the correct results

Comment: Please paste your changed code, and provide what the input and expected output result if possible.

Comment: done and i expect a result given choice of either pass, compensation pass or fail based on their cw module weighting, then the cw mark and exam mark combined

Comment: Just paste the code in mt reply. In my test, "pass, compensation pass and fail" are included in the results. You can run it once and see if the result is working fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you've asked for tips to improve your program as well, without specific code, then I would consider doing the following:

1) Have separate arrays for exam and cw marks. You're making it hard for yourself to debug your program by concatenating them together and this is also the source of your error.

2) Assuming that you always have the same number of exams as you do cw elements then I would consider having a class variable in `MarkCalculator` that stores the number of tests. Something like this:

`private static int NUM_TESTS`.

This way you can initialise arrays like this:

`private static int[] examMarks = new int[NUM_TESTS]`

and you can do the looping in `computeMarks` like this:

`for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++)`

This way if you decide you want more tests you only have to update the code in one place. It would also be easy to change your program so that the user could define how many tests should be calculated.

3) Where you have:

```
weighting = kb.nextInt();
weightings[i] = weighting;
```

replace it with:

`weightings[i] = kb.nextInt();`

as the variable weighting only seem to be used in this place and is therefore unnecessary. This will result in fewer operations the program has to perform and reduces the amount of code on the screen. In practice the compiler will likely remove this redundant variable, but it is good practice to think about how many operations you are performing and which of them aren't necessary.

4) It's better practice to explicitly set access modifiers on fields in a class. So you should have:

'private static int[] weightings = new int[NUM_TESTS];`

If you want to access it from another class you would then typically specify a getter method like so:

`public int[] getWeightings() { return weightings; }`

5) This is less important, but I would move `main` to the bottom of the class. In Java it's more typical to see the classes fields first, then the constructor, then public methods, then private methods and have the main at the bottom. In large projects it helps keeping to good style as it makes the code easier to read and understand.

These reference might help you learn more:

[Java Coding Style Guide](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html)

[Oracle Tutorial on access-modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)